# how to use android-support-v7 ActionBar for version 2.2

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I want to have actionbar in my Android Project using android.support.v7.appcompat; and use it in android 2.2 API Version 8.

I Installed Android support library from SDK Manager, and also added the **android-support-v7-appcompat** from **/extras/android/Compatibility/v7/**

but the current version of this project is 4.2 (the last version of SDK I have already downloaded). When I add this project as a reference to my project I get error (my resurce file (R) has error and couldn't use **R.layout.main**)

how can I solve my Problem and use support.v7 ActionBar?

Comment: "When I add this project as a reference to my project I get error (my resurce file (R) has error and couldn't use R.layout.main)" -- what is the error?

Comment: the Error Text is : "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You should have errors associated with one or more of your resources, or perhaps the manifest, which is preventing `R` from being generated.

Comment: I don't think so; I just Created a project; without any extra code; if I remove the Support-Project from Library; Every things go well;

Comment: as I wrote; the support-project is Android 4.2 and my Project is Android 2.2; if Change it to Android 4.2; I don't have problem; how can use Support-Library project in Android 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if Change it to Android 4.2; I don't have problem

You are forcing us to have to guess what "it" is.

If "it" is your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse), please set that to something like 4.2. **This does not control what versions of Android your app runs on**. Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to be 8 (for Android 2.2), as *that* is what controls what versions of Android your app runs on. Lint will tell you when you are using things that are legal for your build target, but newer than your `android:minSdkVersion`, so you can make sure that you are using those things appropriately.

Comment: Yeah; you right; I thought if I change it to 4.2 the minSdkVersion will Increase Automatically; thanks for helping and tip